# How to parse multiple dictionary values that have the same key

Tags: python, json, dictionary, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I have many lines of data (I can not modify it manually) which is represented as a dictionary as a key/value pairs. The problem is there is one dictionary key that can appear multiple time (for undefined number: may be twice, three times, 10 times, etc.) with different values.

I need to extract all these values.

This is a simple record with two values for the key `Key-Word`:

> {"Date": "Fri, 19 Apr 2019 00:54:46 GMT", "Vary":
>   "Host,Accept-Encoding", "Key-Word": "00a", "Cache-Control": "private",
>   "Key-Word": "xn"}

I wrote this python script to extract the record's value.

```
import ast
import re
import json


inFile = open("sample.txt","r",errors="replace") 


cP=0 # key found flag
cV=0 # hold the key's value


try:
    myDict = {"Date": "Fri, 19 Apr 2019 00:54:46 GMT", "Vary": "Host,Accept-Encoding", "Key-Word": "00a", "Cache-Control": "private", "Key-Word": "xn"}
    smallmyDict= {}

except (ValueError, SyntaxError) as E:
    cV="error"
except Exception as E:
    cV="error"

# convert the header's key to small letter
for key, value in myDict.items():
    smallmyDict[key.lower()] = value

# store all keys
smallmyDictKeys =smallmyDict.keys()



# search for a specific key
if 'key-word' in smallmyDictKeys: 
    cP=1
    cV = smallmyDict['key-word']
    print("Found!")
    print(cV) #print the key's value
else:
    print("NOT Found!")
```

The output I get is:

> Found! xn

The problem is that it prints the last key's value only.

How can I make my code iterate over the key I am looking for if it appeared multiple times and print each value separately rather than overwrite it with the last value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json` to parse your data, and use the `object_pairs_hook` parameter of the [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) to personalize the treatment of the data. In the example below, I grouped the different values for the same keys in a list (and, as requested in your comment, concatenated them in a string):

```
import json
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

data = """{"Date": "Fri, 19 Apr 2019 00:54:46 GMT", "Vary": "Host,Accept-Encoding", "Key-Word": "00a", "Cache-Control": "private", "Key-Word": "xn"}

"""

def duplicate_keys(pairs):
    out = {}
    dups = defaultdict(list)
    key_count = Counter(key for key, value in pairs)

    for key, value in pairs:
        if key_count[key] == 1:
            out[key] = value
        else:
            dups[key].append(value)

    # Concatenate the lists of values in a string, enclosed in {} and separated by ';'
    # rather than in a list:       
    dups = {key: ';'.join('{' + v + '}' for v in values) for key, values in dups.items()}

    out.update(dups)
    return out

decoded = json.loads(data, object_pairs_hook=duplicate_keys)
print(decoded)

# {'Date': 'Fri, 19 Apr 2019 00:54:46 GMT', 
#  'Vary': 'Host,Accept-Encoding', 
#  'Cache-Control': 'private', 
#  'Key-Word': '{00a};{xn}'}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I separate the array items with a character other than comma?

Comment: Yes, if you prefer to have them all in a string rather than as a list. I edited the answer.

Comment: Didn't see you already did this. Definitely seems like the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry can you point to me how to store them as: {value1};{value2},etc. I just prefer to add curly brackets to them.

Comment: Here you have them. Though, depending on your use case, lists of values might be more versatile. Your choice!

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the string and store the values in a dictionary as lists:

```
import ast
from pprint import pprint

def parse_dict_multikey(s):
    p = ast.parse(s)
    exp_dict = p.body[0].value
    keys = list(map(ast.literal_eval, exp_dict.keys))
    values = list(map(ast.literal_eval, exp_dict.values))
    d = {}
    for k, v in zip(keys, values):
        d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
    return d

s = ('{"Date": "Fri, 19 Apr 2019 00:54:46 GMT",'
     ' "Vary": "Host,Accept-Encoding",'
     ' "Key-Word": "00a",'
     ' "Cache-Control": "private",'
     ' "Key-Word": "xn"}')
pprint(parse_dict_multikey(s))
# {'Cache-Control': ['private'],
#  'Date': ['Fri, 19 Apr 2019 00:54:46 GMT'],
#  'Key-Word': ['00a', 'xn'],
#  'Vary': ['Host,Accept-Encoding']}
```

This makes every value into a list, though, not only those with repeated keys. You can avoid that if you use a `Counter`, as [Thierry Lathuille](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57081742/1782792) suggests:

```
def parse_dict_multikey(s):
    p = ast.parse(s)
    exp_dict = p.body[0].value
    keys = list(map(ast.literal_eval, exp_dict.keys))
    values = list(map(ast.literal_eval, exp_dict.values))
    c = Counter(keys)
    d = {}
    for k, v in zip(keys, values):
        if c[k] > 1:
            d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
        else:
            d[k] = v
    return d
```

Which would give you:

```
{'Cache-Control': 'private',
 'Date': 'Fri, 19 Apr 2019 00:54:46 GMT',
 'Key-Word': ['00a', 'xn'],
 'Vary': 'Host,Accept-Encoding'}
```

You can also look into something more advanced like [multidict](https://multidict.readthedocs.io).

Comment: Can I separate the array values with a letter other than semicolon, e.g. `>`

Comment: @qbq The advantage of using `:` is that it is the standard Python syntax for dictionaries, so it is easy to parse it with `ast`. If you use something else, like `>`, then you have to do the parsing yourself, which can be complicated if you want to make sure that, for example, you do not use a `>` within a string as a separator. So, you could use a different syntax, but it would be more work, unless you put some restrictions on it (e.g. assume that strings will never contain `>`).

Comment: @qbq That I meant about the input data (the string that you have to parse), or you were talking about printing that parsed data later? That, you can print however you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have 2 keys of the same name in a dictionary. One will overwrite the other. During runtime, only one pair of that key will exist(the last entry).

https://www.python-course.eu/dictionaries.php - is a good resource to read about a dictionary.

Comment: Any suggestions for other methods to parse this? The data are stored in a file, each record in a line. Is there any way other than this?

Comment: I would suggest adding some postfix to the key so you can differentiate the 2. e.g `key_word_a` and `key_word_b` @qbq

Answer (score 0):

Since your data cannot directly be loaded into json because of duplicate keys, try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

string = '{"Date": "Fri, 19 Apr 2019 00:54:46 GMT", "Vary": "Host,Accept-Encoding", "Key-Word": "00a", "Cache-Control": "private", "Key-Word": "xn"}'

pieces = string.split('",')

for each_piece in pieces:
    key, value = each_piece.split(':', maxsplit=1)
    actual_key = key.strip('{"')
    actual_value = value.strip(' "')
    data[actual_key].append(actual_value)

print(data)
```

**output**:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {' "Cache-Control': ['private'],
             ' "Key-Word': ['00a', 'xn"}'],
             ' "Vary': ['Host,Accept-Encoding'],
             'Date': ['Fri, 19 Apr 2019 00:54:46 GMT']})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define the dict `myDict = {"Date": "Fri, 19 Apr 2019 00:54:46 GMT", "Vary": "Host,Accept-Encoding", "Key-Word": "00a", "Cache-Control": "private", "Key-Word": "xn"}` you need have different keys to values: `00a` and `xn`.

Can you use/convert to string `some_str = '{"Date": "Fri, 19 Apr 2019 00:54:46 GMT", "Vary": "Host,Accept-Encoding", "Key-Word": "00a", "Cache-Control": "private", "Key-Word": "xn"}'`.